# CSS - two divs "floating" right absolute in div relative

Tags: css, absolute

The puzzle I'm trying to solve today requires a post div, inside which is a post thumbnail. On top of (layered over) that thumb image, based on php queries (that work great) I need two icons that align to the right behind each other. By 'behind' I mean X-axis, because right now due to the position:absolute they stack on the Z-axis so one is hidden.
What this is is a post that can have a veriety of illustrated car icons (that align right), but in some cases, a trailer icon is needed. So the trailer needs to follow behind the car.
Trick is, each of the cars and each of the trailers has a different picture width.
Here's what I have so far, everything works except the trailer is hidden behind the car.

```
.post {margin:0; padding:12px; border:1px solid #fff; -khtml-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; position: relative;}

.carortrailer {display:block; position:absolute; right: 0; height:32px; margin-top:130px; margin-right: 4px; padding:0; z-index:990; }

.car {background:url("images/ico-car.png") no-repeat scroll right; width: 70px;}

.trailer {background:url("images/ico-trailer.png") no-repeat scroll right; width: 66px;}
```

php

```
<div class="post-block">
<?php if (($post->cp_pvs) == 'trailer') echo '<div class="carortrailer trailer"></div>'; else if... ?>
<?php if (($post->cp_car) == 'car') echo '<div class="carortrailer car"></div>'; else if... ?>
<div class="thumb"><?php if ( $opt->images ) thumbnail(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Btw: I understand this would be very easy if without the icons over the thumb, but that's a requirement unfortunately. Also making icons of the car+trailer would be possible so as to have just one car div, although there are many combinations of car+trailer, so I don't like that idea much.
Any help is much appreciated ;)

Comment: Oooh, got it! .trailer and .car need to be divs inside the .carortrailer div, just with height and float:left.